# Stop MySQL query with keyboard shortcut

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Is there a way that I can stop/kill an running SQL query with some keyboard shortcut?

I'm using MariaDB.

Comment: are you crazy? what ide do you use so?

Comment: MariaDB is a headless server that doesn't have any GUI. The only way to interact with it is a client program. Also, what do you want exactly? Hit the keyboard and get some random query killed?

Comment: I write SQL comand is a shell, and one query is running a long time. SO is there a way to kill it without exiting the shell

Comment: you can use 2 things. from the MySQL Client you can use use [ctrl]-C or you start a second connection and enter **SHOW PROCESSLIST;** look for the query and type **KILL ID** where ID is the id of the first column from show processlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample for [ctrl]-C

**sample [ctrl]-C**

```
MariaDB [yourschema]> select sleep(999);
^CCtrl-C -- query killed. Continuing normally.
+------------+
| sleep(999) |
+------------+
+------------+
1 row in set (2.12 sec)
```

MariaDB [yourschema]>

**Sample KILL**

window 1

```
MariaDB [yourschema]> select sleep(999);
```

window 2

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show processlist;
+--------+-----------------+-----------------+------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+-------------------+----------+
| Id     | User            | Host            | db         | Command | Time    | State                       | Info              | Progress |
+--------+-----------------+-----------------+------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+-------------------+----------+
|     34 | event_scheduler | localhost       | NULL       | Daemon  | 1340348 | Waiting for next activation | NULL              |    0.000 |
|  43607 | root            | localhost:65119 | yourSchema | Sleep   |      20 |                             | NULL              |    0.000 |
|  43609 | root            | localhost:65120 | NULL       | Sleep   |      58 |                             | NULL              |    0.000 |
|  80450 | root            | localhost:51083 | yourSchema | Sleep   |      68 |                             | NULL              |    0.000 |
|  80452 | root            | localhost:51084 | NULL       | Sleep   |      45 |                             | NULL              |    0.000 |
|  80545 | root            | localhost:51184 | yourSchema | Sleep   |       3 |                             | NULL              |    0.000 |
|  80546 | root            | localhost:51185 | NULL       | Sleep   |       3 |                             | NULL              |    0.000 |
| 129783 | root            | localhost       | yourschema | Query   |       9 | User sleep                  | select sleep(999) |    0.000 |
| 129809 | root            | localhost       | NULL       | Query   |       0 | init                        | show processlist  |    0.000 |
+--------+-----------------+-----------------+------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+-------------------+----------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> kill 129783;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

window 1

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
MariaDB [yourschema]>
```